# line chart with dropdown in Bokeh stand-alone doesn't work

Tags: python, html, visualization, bokeh

I am building a simple HTML file to represent some data in the chart graph with dropdown but the callback for such interactivity doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import layouts

output_file("churn_graph.html", title="line_on_off.py example")

df_3_days = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data1.xlsx", sheet_name="3 days")
df_40_days = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data2.xlsx", sheet_name="40 days")
df_365_days = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\data3.xlsx", sheet_name="365 days")

x = df_3_days['Month']
churn_3d_12m_all = df_3_days['churnRate_12m_all']
churn_3d_12m_b2b = df_3_days['churnRate_12m_B2B']
churn_3d_12m_b2c = df_3_days['churnRate_12m_B2C']
churn_3d_6m = df_3_days['churnRate_6m_all']

churn_40d_12m_all = df_40_days['churnRate_12m_all']
churn_40d_12m_b2b = df_40_days['churnRate_12m_B2B']
churn_40d_12m_b2c = df_40_days['churnRate_12m_B2C']
churn_40d_6m = df_40_days['churnRate_6m_all']

churn_365d_12m_all = df_365_days['churnRate_12m_all']
churn_365d_12m_b2b = df_365_days['churnRate_12m_B2B']
churn_365d_12m_b2c = df_365_days['churnRate_12m_B2C']
churn_365d_6m = df_365_days['churnRate_6m_all']

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'x' : x, 'y3_12all' : churn_3d_12m_all,
    'x' : x, 'y3_12B2B' : churn_3d_12m_b2b,
    'x' : x, 'y3_12B2C' : churn_3d_12m_b2c,
    'x' : x, 'y3_6m' : churn_3d_6m
})

p = figure(width=500, height=250)

y3_12all = p.line(x, churn_3d_12m_all, color='blue', legend_label="3 days, 12m all")
y3_12B2B = p.line(x, churn_3d_12m_b2b, color='brown', legend_label="3 days B2B")
y3_12B2C = p.line(x, churn_3d_12m_b2c, color='red', legend_label="3 days B2C")
y3_6m = p.line(x, churn_3d_6m, color='green', legend_label="3 days, 6m")

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    y3_12all = data['y3_12all']
    y3_12B2B = data['y3_12B2B']
    y3_12B2C = data['y3_12B2C']
    y3_6m = data['y3_6m']
    if (f == "y3_12all"){
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12all.length; i++) {y3_12all[i] = y3_12all[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12B2B.length; i++) {y3_12B2B[i] = 'nan'}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12B2C.length; i++) {y3_12B2C[i] = 'nan'}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_6m.length; i++) {y3_6m[i] = 'nan'}
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12all.length; i++) {y3_12all[i] = y3_12all[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12B2B.length; i++) {y3_12B2B[i] = y3_12B2B[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_12B2C.length; i++) {y3_12B2C[i] = y3_12B2C[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < y3_6m.length; i++) {y3_6m[i] = y3_6m[i]}
    }
    source.trigger('change');
""")
buffers = ['12m all', '12m B2B', '12m B2C', '6m', 'all']
multi_select = Select(title="Select buffer: ", value=buffers[4], options=buffers, callback=callback)
output_file("churn_chart.html")

layout = layouts.VBox(multi_select, p)
show(layout)
```

After running I receive the message: "unexpected attribute 'callback' to Select, similar attributes are js_event_callbacks".
Any suggestions on how to fix it?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

From the changelog for 2.0.0 at https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/releases.html#api-removals:

> Additionally, the `callback` property is removed from all Bokeh models except `CustomAction`, `HoverTool`, `TapTool`, and `OpenURL`. Instead, the more general `js_on_change` or `js_on_event` methods should be used.

Try removing the `callback` argument to `Select` and adding something like

```py
multi_select.js_on_change('value', callback)
```

Not related to your question, but you also might consider these changes:

- Replace `source.get('data')` with `source.data`
- Similarly, replace `cb_obj.get('value')` with `cb_obj.value`

Also, I'm not sure if `'nan'` strings are a good approach. You can just use `NaN` if they cause any trouble.